# Zero-padding a plot

Tags: matlab

I am using the following code to plot a window:

```
m = ((33-1)/2)
n = -m:m
w = 0.54 + 0.46 *cos(pi*n/m)
stem(0: numel(w)-1, w)
```

This is giving the following plot:

[image]

Now I tried zero-padding the window with 200. I used the following code:

```
m = ((33-1)/2)
n = -m:m
w = 0.54 + 0.46 *cos(pi*n/m)
w_zp = padarray(w, 200, 'pre')
stem(0: numel(w_zp)-1, w_zp)
```

Why is this not working please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `padarray`, but for such a simple example you might as well use (assuming `w` is a row vector as in your code):

```
Npre = 100;    % # zeros before w
Npost = 100;   % # zeros after w
w_zp = [zeros(1,Npre), w, zeros(1,Npost)];
```